# ¿Cómo eliminar los dobles paréntesis en una tupla?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este código

```
def main():
    l = [ ('Hola', 'don Pepito'), ('Hola', 'don Jose'), ('Hola', 'don Luis'),('Buenos', 'días') ]
    print (tuplas_a_diccionario(l))

def tuplas_a_diccionario(l):
    saludos = {}
    for i in l:
        if i[0] in saludos:
            saludos[i[0]] = saludos[i[0]],i[1]
        else:
            saludos[i[0]] =  i[1]
    return saludos
main()
```

el resultado es:

```
{'Hola': (('don Pepito', 'don Jose'), 'don Luis'), 'Buenos': 'días'}
```

Quisiera saber cómo eliminar los dobles paréntesis en la tupla.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que lo que pretendes es obtener un diccionario en el que las claves sean los "saludos", y los valores sean listas de cadenas, como el siguiente:

```
{'Buenos': ['días'], 'Hola': ['don Pepito', 'don Jose', 'don Luis']}
```

En este caso la solución es:

- Crea un diccionario vacío
- Para cada elemento de tu lista de tuplas, separa el "saludo" del "resto"

  - Si el saludo no está el diccionario, añade al diccionario esa clave, usando como valor una lista vacía
  - Añade a la lista el "resto"

Observa que la instrucción que "Añade a la lista" se hace siempre, tanto si el saludo existía como si no. Si el diccionario ya tenía esa clave (y por tanto una lista asociada), la lista se aumentará con un valor adicional. Si no la tenía, en la línea anterior nos aseguramos de que la tenga (con una lista vacía a la que seguidamente añadiríamos el valor).

Ese pseudocódigo se traduce directamente a python:

```
l = [ ('Hola', 'don Pepito'), ('Hola', 'don Jose'), 
      ('Hola', 'don Luis'),('Buenos', 'días') ]
d = {}
for saludo, resto in l:
  if saludo not in d:
    d[saludo] = []
  d[saludo].append(resto)
```

### Bonus

La biblioteca `collections` tiene la clase `defaultdict` que puede simplificar el código anterior, al evitar tener que mirar si la clave estaba antes o no en el diccionario:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for saludo, resto in l:
  d[saludo].append(resto)
```

Un `defaultdict` nunca da error si al usar `d[saludo]` el saludo no estaba, sino que en ese caso creará ese elemento del diccionario, dándole como valor una lista vacía (porque hemos creado el defaultdict pasándole `list` como parámetro).

## Ampliación (usando tuplas)

El título original de la pregunta era "Agregar listas a diccionarios" y en ese sentido iba todo lo anterior en esta respuesta.

Pero si lo que se quiere en cambio es que el diccionario resultante tenga tuplas, la cuestión cambia, pues las tuplas (a diferencia de las listas) son inmutables por lo que no es posible ir añadiéndoles elementos mediante `append()`.

Sí es posible en cambio crear en cada iteración una tupla nueva, que sea igual a la anterior pero con un elemento adicional. La forma más simple es usar concatenación de tuplas. Por ejemplo `(1,) + (2,)` concatena una tupla que contiene un 1 con otra que contiene un 2. El resultado es una tupla nueva de valor `(1,2)`. Se puede asignar esta nueva tupla a la clave del diccionario donde antes había otra tupla.

Es más, las tuplas soportan incluso el operador `+=`:

```
a = (1,)
a += (2,)
print(a)  # (1,2)
```

produciendo la "ilusión" de que se ha añadido un elemento a la tupla (en realidad se ha creado una tupla nueva, con un elemento adicional, y se ha reasignado la variable para que apunte a la nueva tupla)

Usando ese operador:

```
l = [ ('Hola', 'don Pepito'), ('Hola', 'don Jose'), 
      ('Hola', 'don Luis'),('Buenos', 'días') ]
d = {}
for saludo, resto in l:
  if saludo not in d:
    d[saludo] = tuple()  # Tupla vacía
  d[saludo]+=(resto,)    # Añadirle un elemento
```

Resultado:

```
{'Buenos': ('días',), 'Hola': ('don Pepito', 'don Jose', 'don Luis')}
```

`defaultdict` también puede ser usado en este caso:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(tuple)
for saludo, resto in l:
  d[saludo]+=(resto,)
```

Comment: También sería posible usar `tuple` como constructor del `defaultdict`: `d = defaultdict(tuple)`. En lugar del _append_, `d[saludo] = d[saludo] + (resto,)`

Comment: @ChemaCortes Sí, o incluso `d[saludo]+=(resto,)` funciona también con `defaultdict` pero no quise alargar más la respuesta. Supuse que se deducía de lo anterior. Pero lo añadiré para que quede más completo.